# Angular and Spring boot -> POST Request response 403

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, apache, tomcat

I have a problem with Spring boot and Angular. I make a POST request which works on POSTMAN and locally but which gives me a 403 in production on tomcat with apache as reverse proxy. But it's working when I am with the embedded tomcat.

I have to try everything soon.

All the solutions I've seen say to disable CSFR but I have no authentication to access my webservice and therefore no spring-security dependency.

I tried anyway but the problem is still there. And in some cases it required me to log in which I don't want to do

```
import ch.megahertz.swissqrbillsgeneratorapi.properties.FileStorageProperties;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"ch.megahertz.swissqrbillsgeneratorapi.*"})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({
        FileStorageProperties.class
})

public class SwissQrBillsGeneratorApiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SwissQrBillsGeneratorApiApplication.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Run application");
        SpringApplication.run(SwissQrBillsGeneratorApiApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {

        return application.sources(SwissQrBillsGeneratorApiApplication.class);
    }



}


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowCredentials(false)
                .maxAge(-1);
    }

}


import ch.megahertz.swissqrbillsgeneratorapi.payload.Invoice;
import ch.megahertz.swissqrbillsgeneratorapi.service.CRMService;
import ch.megahertz.swissqrbillsgeneratorapi.service.FileStorageService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;


//@CrossOrigin(origins = {"https://swissqrbillsgenerator.megahertz.ch/","http://localhost:4200/"})
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class ApiController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiController.class);

    @Autowired
    private FileStorageService fileStorageService;

    @Autowired
    private CRMService crmService;

    @GetMapping
    public String generateQRBills() {
        log.info("Enter in GeT API");
    return "Get ok";
    }

    @PostMapping("/generate")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Enter in generate API");
        logger.info("Enter in generate API");
        log.info("Enter in generate POST API");
        String fileName = fileStorageService.storeFile(file);

        String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("/downloadFile/")
                .path(fileName)
                .toUriString();

        Invoice facture = crmService.getFactureInfo(fileName);
        File fileWithQR = fileStorageService.addQrToFile(fileName, facture);

        Resource resource = new UrlResource(fileWithQR.toURI());
           return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,Files.probeContentType(resource.getFile().toPath()))
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName+ "\"")
                    .body(resource);


    }
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: If you getting 403, I might try these: first recreate your pom file and make sure sevurity is not there. Second, you showing the contrller with  the file with RequestParamter which is good but you don't show the web app code that send the file/request.

Comment: I don't have any problem when i run the application with mvn spring-boot:run only when i am one a external tomcat

Answer (score 0):

If Postman is returning the query, then the problem is probably in the Angular front end. I believe I was getting a 403 error when I tried to send a String from my backend, it had to be wrapped in an object and unwrapped by Angular to be a string in Angular.